# Fetching (strongly typed) related entities using FetchXML

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm using fetchXML to join two entities and can only get the results for the first list. I'm probably making a silly mistake, but this has me mucking around for hours.

```
var query = @"
  <fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='contact'>
    <all-attributes />
    <link-entity name='new_custom' from='new_contactid' to='contactid' link-type='inner'>
      <all-attributes />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
";

var fe = new FetchExpression(query);
var result = service.RetrieveMultiple(fe);

// This contact entity is properly filled
var contact = result.Entities.First().Cast<Contact>();

// This relationship is null, that's unexpected!
var custom = contact.new_contact_new_custom;

// Also null (not sure if this should work)
var related = contact.GetRelatedEntity<new_custom>("new_contact_new_custom", null);
```

I do see that the correct data was retrieved in the `Attributes` and `FormattedValues` properties on the Contact entity. But why isn't the relationship set up correctly? And how can I cast this data to the correct "custom" entity type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: are you sure your query returns early-bound objects? In my example below I assume you get Entity objects (late-bound), but for this example it would not really make much of a difference.

The query's response is basically a plain table of entity objects of the type you requested, in this case "contact". Fields of joined entities can be added to this table too, but they are wrapped in `AliasedValue` objects. Their column names are prefixed by a `LinkEntity` alias in order to prevent name collisions.

Your line `var contact = result.Entities.Cast<Contact>();` suggests that variable `contact` is of type `Contact`, but it is in fact an `IEnumerable<Contact>`. (Using `var` is not always that helpful.) For this reason I suspect your last two lines do not even compile.

In the example below a fetch-query is sent to the Organization.svc endpoint. (Note the alias attribute.) Then field "new_name" of entity "new_custom" is taken from the first row of the query's resultset.

```
var fetchXml = @"
    <fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
        <entity name='contact'>
        <all-attributes />
        <link-entity name='new_custom' alias='nc' from='new_contactid' to='contactid' link-type='inner'>
            <all-attributes />
        </link-entity>
        </entity>
    </fetch>
";

var query = new FetchExpression(fetchXml);
var response = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
var contact = response.Entities[0];
var customField = contact.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("nc.new_name");
string name = customField != null ? (string)customField.Value : null;
```

Comment: Sorry about the non-comiling example, fixed it. So it's only possible to fetch attributes from linked entities? I'd like to get a bound entity object (without sending two queries).

Comment: To answer your first question: yes, I'm using early-bound entities. Also, the relationship from Contact to new_custom is 1:M.

Comment: I don't think you can get linked entity objects from a FetchXml query in an easy way. I'm afraid you would have to develop some helper code to make that work.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a late answer, but the question helped me get on the right track so I thought I'd add my piece. Like Henk says in the comments to his answer, you can implement a relatively simple extension method to parse out the fields of a linked entity into another entity, then cast that as an early-bound type. All you need to know is the alias you used for the `link-entity` element. Here's my implementation (EDIT: Added FormattedValues):

```
    public static T ToRelatedEntity<T>(this Entity rawEntity, string relatedAlias)
        where T:CrmEntity, new() 
        //CrmEntity is a base class I insert into my generated code 
        //to differentiate early-bound classes; you can use Entity
    {
        var result = new Entity(new T().LogicalName);

        foreach(var attribute in rawEntity.Attributes
                                    .Where(kvp=>kvp.Key
                                              .StartsWith(relatedAlias + ".")))
        {
            var newName = attribute.Key.Replace(relatedAlias + ".", String.Empty);
            result[newName] = ((AliasedValue)attribute.Value).Value;
        }
        foreach(var formattedValue in rawEntity.FormattedValues
                                        .Where(kvp=>kvp.Key
                                                  .StartsWith(relatedAlias + ".")))
        {
            var newName = formattedValue.Key.Replace(relatedAlias + ".", String.Empty);
            result.FormattedValues[newName] = formattedValue.Value;
        }

        return result.ToEntity<T>();
    }

//usage
var query = new FetchExpression(fetchXml);
var response = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
var contact = response.Entities[0].ToEntity<Contact>();
var newCustom = response.Entities[0].ToRelatedEntity<new_custom>("nc");
```

Very basic, but it seems to work quite well as long as you're not aliasing any of the fields you're retrieving, and you're retrieving enough information to populate a valid instance of the object (Id, primary field, etc). It's much better than trying to instantiate the related object with an initializer (especially since many fields like `StateCode` are read-only).